# [flutter]I cannot use BlendMode.srcIn in Paint

Tags: flutter, paint

I want to use paint to realize an effect like ClipRRect.

```
class SignaturePainter extends CustomPainter {
  ...
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = new Paint()..color = Colors.blue[200];
    canvas.drawImageRect(image,Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble()),Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 400,400),paint);
    paint.blendMode = BlendMode.srcIn;
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(200, 200), 50, paint);
  }
}
```

it seems that BlendMode.srcIn doesn't work, but if I change BlendMode to BlendMode to other value, it works, how to resolve it?My device is Nokia7 Plus.

Comment: any error messages appearing when you run the code ?

Comment: if you want "ClipRRect effect" you should use `dstIn` imho

Comment: @Mazin Ibrahim,no any error messages appearing.

Comment: @pskink, you are right,it's should be dstIn. I forget i have modified the code. It still doesn't work, If I change the value to lighten or darken, it works.

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23335) code, change `paint.blendMode = BlendMode.modulate;` to `dstIn`

Comment: @pskink ,very sorry to reply you so later,it works ,but isn't my wanted.it seems that only dstIn and srcIn doesn't work.